# Inherit from abstract class with multiply vars in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have an abstract class with multiply vars :

```
abstract class Animal(var name: String, var age: Int, var mother: Animal, 
                      var father: Animal, var friends: ArrayList<Animal>)
```

Now, as you probably guessed, I want to create 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Parrot', etc classes deriving from Animal.

However, when I define Cat class, I don't know whats the name, age, ... fields, so the code doesn't compile.

```
class Cat : Animal()
```

Doesn't compile, since we need to pass here variables we don't know yet.

Another question would be:
How to initiate an inner class within a class? A cat has both mother and father who are cats as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the documentation about [inheritance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#inheritance)

Since you have a primary constructor you will have to pass the parameters to `super`:

```
abstract class Animal(var name: String, var age: Int, var mother: Animal, 
                      var father: Animal, var friends: ArrayList<Animal>)

class Cat(name: String, age: Int, mother: Animal, 
          father: Animal, friends: ArrayList<Animal>) 
          : Animal(name, age, mother, father, friends)
```

Comment: Thanks, without vars it compiles : class Cat(name: String, age: Int, mother: Animal,
          father: Animal, friends: ArrayList<Animal>)
    : Animal(name, age, mother, father, friends)

Comment: True, since it's not defining a new property but just receiving it at the constructor var is not necessary. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 4):

You could specify your Animal class without a construtor and define the constructor(s) only in the subtype.

```
abstract class Animal {
    var name = ""
    var age = 0
    lateinit var mother: Animal
    lateinit var father: Animal
    lateinit var friends: ArrayList<Animal>
}

class Cat: Animal {

    // only initialize the fields you need for this specific type
    constructor(n: String) {
        name = n
    }

    // define a second constructor for your second question
    constructor(m: Animal, f: Animal) {
        mother = m
        father = f
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, you can use generics to help with scope

e.g.

```
abstract class Animal<T : Animal<T>>(
    var name: String,
    var age: Int,
    var mother: T, 
    var father: T,
    var friends: MutableList<Animal>
)

class Cat(
    name: String,
    age: Int,
    mother: Cat,
    father: Cat,
    friends: MutableList<Animal>
) : Animal<Cat>(name, age, mother, father, friends)
```